# Controls disappear when reaching end of audio only title with MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ios, audio, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am using MPMoviePlayerController to play audio and video on an iPad. If an audio only title (an mp3 in this case) is playing and reaches the end the playback controls disappear and there is no way to get them to show again. What I want to have happen is for the controls to stick around and for the title to be scrubbable.  I did try setting the repeatMode to MPMovieRepeatModeOne but that seems to have no effect on audio only titles. I did read a post that if you were using MPMoviePlayerViewController to remove the observer for the MPMoviePlayerViewController instance but I am using MPMoviePlayerController. Any ideas would be appreciated.